# Array elements not displaying in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to Javascript. Below is simple program where I am trying to display elements from array that I have created. It does not work. Can anybody please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Javascript Excercises - Functions</title>
    <script>            
        function findPrimeFactors(){
            var primefacts = [];
            var primefacs;
            var unum = prompt("Please enter a positive number");
            var i = 2;
            var num = parseInt(unum);

            if (num > 0) {             


                while (num >= i){
                    if (num % i == 0){
                        primefacts.push(i);
                        num = num / i;

                        console.log("Prime factor: " + i + " New num: " + num + " Array length: " + primefacts.length + " Last array element: " + primefacts[primefacts.length-1]); 
                    }
                    else {
                        i += 1;
                    }

                };


                if (primefacts.length = 0) {
                    document.write("No prime factors other than 1 for this number.");
                }
                else {
                    primefacs = primefacts.join();
                    console.log("Prime factors: " + primefacts[0] + ", " + primefacts[1] + ", " + primefacts[2]);
                    document.write("The prime factor for " + unum + " are : " + primefacs);
                }

            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>        
    <button  onclick="findPrimeFactors()">Click to proceed</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you add a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your working code? That code isn't formatted well and it's hard to follow.

Comment: Sorry, Can you elaborate? Do not know what you mean.

Comment: Click the link I put in the previous comment, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly to make it better. "It does not work" is not a sufficient problem description.

Comment: One person really thinks "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"?

Answer (score 1):

replace:-

```
if (primefacts.length = 0) {
```

with

```
if (primefacts.length == 0) {
```

you are setting the `length` to 0 instead of comparing.

```js
function findPrimeFactors() {
  var primefacts = [];
  var primefacs;
  var unum = prompt("Please enter a positive number");
  var i = 2;
  var num = parseInt(unum);

  if (num > 0) {


    while (num >= i) {
      if (num % i == 0) {
        primefacts.push(i);
        num = num / i;

        console.log("Prime factor: " + i + " New num: " + num + " Array length: " + primefacts.length + " Last array element: " + primefacts[primefacts.length - 1]);
      } else {
        i += 1;
      }

    };


    if (primefacts.length == 0) {
      document.write("No prime factors other than 1 for this number.");
    } else {
      primefacs = primefacts.join();
      console.log("Prime factors: " + primefacts[0] + ", " + primefacts[1] + ", " + primefacts[2]);
      document.write("The prime factor for " + unum + " are : " + primefacs);
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="findPrimeFactors()">Click to proceed</button>
```

Comment: There's a lot more problems to this than that if you took a bit of time to look at the code.

Comment: care to elaborate? Yes there are but getting the code to *work* as in log and write the numbers then that **is** the issue. fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/808ym7fk/

Comment: That doesn't actually resolve the issue of the button call failing. Resolve that, edit your answer to reflect it, and I'll reverse my downvote.

Comment: it fires the click just fine. just the *snippet* is sandboxed and doesnt allow prompt. see the console:- *Ignored call to 'prompt()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set.*

Comment: Ah, you're right. I didn't realize about the `allow-modals` bit that was causing a problem. Downvote corrected to an upvote.

Comment: Glad I could help. Marking as answered/correct would be appreciated :)